# How to correct "for statement" inside awk command in bash

Tags: for-loop, awk

I would like to find the line containing "author" and replace with "s#" then print out the rest of line. Then print out between "data" and "end", and so please you to take a look at the code and tell me how correct for statement inside awk command.

```
#!/bin/bash
defdatano=6
for datano in $(eval seq 0 1 $(($defdatano - 1)))
do
   { echo $datano 
     awk '/#DATA'$(($datano - 1))'/,/#END/{print;next}; /#AUTHORS/ { sub ("#AUTHORS" , "s'$datano' "); print}' DataInput >> DataOutput }
done
```

Input:

```
REF
TDC
AUTHORS A1
REF
OLD
REF
DATA1
1
2
3
4
5
END
REF
OEF
AUTHORS A2
REF
REF
DATA2
6
7
8
9
10
END
```

Desired Output:

```
s0 A1
DATA1
1
2
3
4
5
END
s1 A2
DATA2
6
7
8
9
10
END
```

Comment: Code I used is 

    !/bin/bash
    defdatano=6
    
        for datano in $(eval seq 0 1 $(($defdatano - 1)))
        do {
          echo $datano
          awk '/#DATA'$(($datano - 1))'/,/#END/{print;next}; /#AUTHORS/ { sub ("#AUTHORS" , "s'$datano' "); print}'  DataInput >> DataOutput
        } done

Comment: $defdatano needs to be changed. It must be 2 for this input file.

Comment: Please edit your Question and add the code your used. Someone who tries to answer your question might not see it, when its just a comment.

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/ for debugging this. You are missing semicolons, and you make use of the bash compound-command `{ list; }` which you also forget to terminate with a `;`

Comment: Never use a range expression `/start/,/end/` as they make the code for trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions for the tiniest requirements change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'sub(/AUTHORS/,"s"c+0){print;c++} /DATA/{f=1} f{print} /END/{f=0}' file
s0 A1
DATA1
1
2
3
4
5
END
s1 A2
DATA2
6
7
8
9
10
END
```

Based on this and your other recent questions you seem to be confused about shell (a tool for sequencing calls to other tools and manipulating files and processes) vs awk (the standard UNIX tool for general-purpose manipulation of text, the tool called by shell when its necessary to manipulate text) and in particular what awk is and how to use it. I highly recommend you get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I will check out the book.

Comment: How I can put  "( double-quote) at end of the line which contains #AUTHORS?

Comment: Change the `print` to `print $0 "\""`.

Comment: Thank you, Ed. I do not why I kept missing small things even though I know exactly $0 prints out the rest of the line. Practice makes perfect, I guess.

Comment: You're welcome. As soon as you read the book all will be revealed :-).

Answer (score 0):

Give this one-liner a try:

```
awk '/^AUTHORS/{$1="s"i++}/^REF/{next}7' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
REF
AUTHORS A1
REF
REF
DATA1
1
2
3
4
5
END
REF
AUTHORS A2
REF
REF
DATA2
6
7
8
9
10
END

kent$  awk '/^AUTHORS/{$1="s"i++}/^REF/{next}7' f
s0 A1
DATA1
1
2
3
4
5
END
s1 A2
DATA2
6
7
8
9
10
END
```

Comment: You literally took out "ref" and printed out desired output file. But "ref" could mean anything "Quality", "Title".  Here is what I wrote. defdatano=2 for datano in $(eval seq 0 1 $(($defdatano - 1))) do { echo $datano awk '/#DATA'$(($datano - 1))'/,/#END/{print;next}; /#AUTHORS/ { sub ("#AUTHORS" , "s'$datano' "); print}' DataInput >> DataOutput } done. İt needs to be improved.

Comment: @usermrt you didn't tell that in your Q, DATA, AUTHORS are fixed text, I thought REF was fixed as well.